# how can I make my animated image cover all background?

Tags: html, css, animation

I've got a an image I'm using as a background that is animated in CSS, but it is push all of my content to the bottom of the page with plain white background.  Does anyone know how I can get it to act more of an animated wallpaper so my content isn't pushed down?

```css
#map {
  height: 400px;
  width: 400px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.check {
  text-align: center;
}

h3,
h2,
h1,
a {
  text-align: center;
  background-color: transparent;
}

#sky {
  overflow: hidden;
}

#clouds {
  width: 200%;
  height: 1000px;
  background-image: url('https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1455735459330-969b65c65b1c?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1652&q=80');
  -webkit-animation: movingclouds 25s linear infinite;
  -moz-animation: movingclouds 25s linear infinite;
  -o-animation: movingclouds 25s linear infinite;
}

@keyframes movingclouds {
  0% {
    margin-left: 0%;
  }
  100% {
    margin-left: -100%;
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="sky">
  <div id="clouds"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: use it as background of body and animate the background position

Comment: What @TemaniAfif said. I was in the process of doing a demo but he beat me to it. https://jsbin.com/ruyemijasi/edit?html,css,js,output

Comment: @AndrewGrothe it was a simple comment, you can consider your demo as an answer. it seems to be a valid one

Comment: @AndrewGrothe Thanks!!  That did it.  I'm still pretty new to this - can you explain why this works?

Comment: Added a comment to my answer to explain what was happening.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Move the animation to the background position. This way, it will animate behind whatever is on top of it. In this case, I've moved the background to the body, but you can use absolute/relative position as well.

By animating the margin, you push *everything* to one side, not just the background.

```
body {

  background-image: url('https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1455735459330-969b65c65b1c?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1652&q=80');
  -webkit-animation: movingclouds 25s linear infinite;
  -moz-animation: movingclouds 25s linear infinite;
  -o-animation: movingclouds 25s linear infinite;
}

@keyframes movingclouds {
  0% {
    background-position: 0%;
  }
  100% {
    background-position: -100%;
  }
}
```

Working example: https://jsbin.com/ruyemijasi/edit?html,css,js,output